# lm called from inside dlply throws "0 (non-NA) cases" error [r]

Tags: r, plyr, lm

I'm using dlply() with a custom function that averages slopes of lm() fits on data that contain some NA values, and I get the error 
"Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases"

This error only happens when I call dlply with two key variables - separating by one variable works fine.

Annoyingly I can't reproduce the error with a simple dataset, so I've posted the problem dataset in my dropbox.

Here's the code, as minimized as possible while still producing an error:

```
masterData <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48901983/SOquestionData.csv", na.strings="#N/A")

workingData <- data.frame(sample = masterData$sample,
                      substrate = masterData$substrate,
                      el1 = masterData$elapsedHr1,
                      F1 = masterData$r1 - masterData$rK)

#This function is trivial as written; in reality it takes the average of many slopes
meanSlope <- function(df) {
     lm1 <- lm(df$F1 ~ df$el1, na.action=na.omit) #changing to na.exclude doesn't help
     slope1 <- lm1$coefficients[2]
     meanSlope <- mean(c(slope1)) 
}

lsGOOD <- dlply(workingData, .(sample), meanSlope) #works fine

lsBAD <- dlply(workingData, .(sample, substrate), meanSlope) #throws error
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: I'd say that the error is informative.  If you look at the values in each subset of your data, I assume you'll find one subset of all `NA`. Try replacing your lm call in your function with something that can identify `all(is.na())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For several of your cross-classifications you have missing covariates:

```
 with(masterData, table(sample, substrate, r1mis = is.na(r1) ) )
#
snipped the nonmissing reports
, , r1mis = TRUE

      substrate
sample 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    3  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    5  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    7  0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3
    8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
    9  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
    10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
    11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
    12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
    13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
    14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
```

This would let you skip over the subsets with insufficient data in this particular data:

```
meanSlope <- function(df) { if ( sum(!is.na(df$el1)) < 2 ) { return(NA) } else {
     lm1 <- lm(df$F1 ~ df$el1, na.action=na.omit) #changing to na.exclude doesn't help
     slope1 <- lm1$coefficients[2]
     meanSlope <- mean(c(slope1)) }
}
```

Although it depends on the missingness being in one particular covariate. A more robust solution would be to use `try` to capture errors and convert to NA's.

```
?try
```

Comment: Oh, I see - I didn't get that lm() was throwing errors instead of NAs. That's helpful advice.

Comment: The way to see what is throwing the error is to execute `traceback()`.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment:

```
my.func <- function(df) {
  data.frame(el1=all(is.na(df$el1)), F1=all(is.na(df$F1)))
}

ddply(workingData, .(sample, substrate), my.func)
```

Shows that you have many sub sets where both F1 and el1 are NA.  (in fact every time one is all na, the other is as well!)

Comment: Thanks to you and @DWin for that point - the thing I don't understand is, how can I get dlply() to put slopes in the list elements when they're available, and NA (or similar) when they're not? I had thought that dlply works on data frame subsets more or less independently so that an NA in one subset won't interfere with the other subsets, but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: More clearly - one way to handle the NAs would be to trap them in the meanSlope function, but I feel like there ought to be a better way...

Comment: `dlply` isn't at fault here.  it is handling each subset independently as you expected.  however, if you feed a subset to `lm` that is all NA it will error.  you tried to handle the case where some values were NA correctly, but you cannot feed `lm` an empty subset, which is what you have if you `na.omit` a subset with all NA.  instead, add a line like `if(all(is.na(df)) return(NA)` before the `lm` call.

Comment: I understand much better now. Thanks!